# Can I Use PartialViewResult with PagedList and show it in a PartialView

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

Hi everyone I have a question, Can I use PagedList in a PartialViewResult Action and show the result in a PartialView?

Here is some code

**Controller Code:**

```
public PartialViewResult CargosPorProyecto(string id, int? page)
    {
        var cargos = db.Cargo.Include(i => i.Proyectos).Where(i => i.NumProyecto.Equals(id)).OrderByDescending(i => i.Fecha);

        if (Request.HttpMethod != "GET")
        {
            page = 1;
        }

        var pageSize = 10;
        var pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        var onePage = cargos.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);


        return PartialView("ListaCargosParcial", ViewBag.OnePage = onePage);
    }
```

In my PartialView i put this code to show the pagination

```
<div class="pagination-right">
    <div class="span12">
       <%: Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.OnePage, page => Url.Action("CargosPorProyecto", new { page = page }), new PagedListRenderOptions { LinkToFirstPageFormat = "<< Primera", LinkToPreviousPageFormat = "< Anterior", LinkToNextPageFormat = "Siguiente >", LinkToLastPageFormat = "&Uacute;ltima >>" })%> 
    </div>                    
    </div>
```

And when i load the page that contains the partialview everything looks good, but when i click in Next ("Siguiente") doesn't load in my partial view.

I hope I explained clearly and thanks for the time.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use AJAX if you want to stay on the same page. For example if you are using jQuery you could subscribe to the click event of the pagination links and then trigger an AJAX request to the corresponding controller action and refresh the partial with the results returned:

```
$(function() {
    $('.pagination-right a').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                // refresh the contents of some container div for the partial
                // make sure you use the correct selector here
                $('#some_container_for_the_partial').html(result);
            }
        });

        // cancel the default action which is a redirect
        return false;
    });
});
```